# Get incorrect data after open Serial Port using C#

Tags: c#, arduino

I am new to access arduino using C#.

I am using Arduino Uno board for serial communication using my C# code. But when i Open the Serial port and wait for some time to ready the serial port, I am getting Question Marks(????) on serial port. I don't know why this happen.

I am using "Threading.Sleep" after opening the port. If i remove it, then it works fine. How can i wait after opening the port? I wants to wait for some time after opening the Serial Port for further process.

Thank you.

**Arduino code:**

```
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
    if (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        String data = Serial.readString();
        Serial.print(data);

        if (data == "Ping")
        {
            Serial.write("OK");
        }

        if (data == "ON") 
        {
            digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        }
        else
        {
            digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        }
    }           
}
```

**C# Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Form1.cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            comboBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (string port in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(port);
                Console.WriteLine("Port Added.");
            }
        }

        private void ConBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();


            if (serialPort1.IsOpen == false)
            {
                serialPort1.Open();

                if (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("value in buffer");
                    string val = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                    Console.WriteLine(val);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("#####");
            string bufferval3 = serialPort1.ReadExisting();   //Question Mark displaying between this.
            Console.WriteLine(bufferval3);
            Console.WriteLine("#####");

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Port Closed.");
            }
        }

        private void DisConBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            Status.Text = "Disconnected";
            Status.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed;
        }

        private void OnBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("ON");
        }

        private void OffBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Write("OFF");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have.

Comment: On your arduino and in your C# code you can configure a Baud-Rate. If I remember correctly on your arduino this is given in the constructor of your Serial. And in the C# code its a property of your SerialPort. Both of these rates HAVE to match. (Personally I always use 38400)

Comment: Regarding your edit (adding code): try setting `SerialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;` before you read any data.

Comment: I have already set baud rate in serial port properties as 115200. But same data getting.

Comment: Maybe opening the port also triggers DTR signal and it restarts the Arduino. Then you're getting some bytes from bootloader (possibly on different speed)